# Possible to read custom objects using the Javascript library?

Tags: javascript, api, custom-object, console

We have a web application which loads up the Salesforce Javascript APIs if a specific querystring parameter is passed in on the login url

For example:

`https://myapp.com/login?client=salesforce`

With the client=salesforce parameter there we load up the following salesforce APIs:

```
<salesforceUrl>/support/api/39.0/interaction.js
<salesforceUrl>/support/console/39.0/integration.js
```

We can then import a call center definition file and configure the softphone view in console mode to load up our application which can then use the salesforce API to open tabs, do searches, screenpops etc.

All of the interactions between salesforce and our applications are currently one way (us pushing information to salesforce).

I would like to know if it is possible to read information from salesforce into my application, especially from custom objects, either from the APIs we currently use or by any other means that is applicable to our setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested in just record creates/edits, you use sforce.console.addPushNotificationListener to receive information when certain objects or fields are updated. If you want to be able to access arbitrary data, you'll want to use [Salesforce Canvas](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_canvas.htm) in order to get a valid session. The [Salesforce Canvas Developer's Guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/206/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/canvas_framework.pdf) goes more in-depth, but basically, by implementing Salesforce Canvas in your web app, you'll have a full session that will allow you to query, insert, update, and delete records, plus access any metadata the user has access to.